# How to store my created objects into a array in Python

Tags: python, arrays

so im new to programming, so for anything hahahahahah.
So im trying to create a simple manegment system by creating a person registration and a room registration, and simply place the amount of people registerd into the amount of room.

Só this is what im up-to:

```
class Person:
    counter = 0 
    persons = []
    def __init__ (self,name,surname):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.id = Person.counter
        Person.counter += 1
        
        
    
    def createPeople(self):
        print(self.name, self.surname)

    def peopleCounter (self):
        print(Person.counter)
        

def storePeople ():
        a = Person.createPeople.append(Person.persons)
        print(a)
        
            
        
person1 = Person("Jack", "Wayne")
person1.createPeople()
person2 = Person("Gabriel", "Jones")
person2.createPeople()

print(Person.counter)

print(storePeople)
```

Comment: What's the error/problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are trying to do is store all persons created in the class attribute `persons`, then this is how you can go about it:

```
class Person:
    counter = 0 
    persons = []
    def __init__ (self,name,surname):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.id = Person.counter
        Person.counter += 1
    
    

    def createPeople(self):
        print(self.name, self.surname)
        Person.persons.append(self.name + ' '+ self.surname) #Every time this method is called, it adds the person to the persons list

    def peopleCounter (self):
        print(Person.counter)
           
person1 = Person("Jack", "Wayne")
person1.createPeople()
person2 = Person("Gabriel", "Jones")
person2.createPeople()

print(Person.counter)

print(Person.persons)
```

> Output from my end

```
Jack Wayne
Gabriel Jones
2
['Jack Wayne', 'Gabriel Jones']
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was what i was actually loooking for